# JQuery UI Tabs - How to prevent styles being applied to content within tabs?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have implemented the JQuery UI tabs and they work great, except for one problem...

All my content's styles / classes are being overriden by JQuery's, which I do not want to happen.For example, I have a text box:

```
<input type="text" id="profileFirstName" name="profileFirstName" class="textMedium" />
```

If I inspect the styles in Firebug, I see this (in this order):

```
.ui-widget :active {
outline:medium none;
}

.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button {
font-family:Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size:1em;
}

input.textMedium {
width:200px;
}
```

As you can see, JQuery has added the ui-widget styles before my own, thus overriding mine.

It is doing this everywhere I have implemented the tabs. How do I set it GLOBALLY so that its styles don't override mine?? I do not want any of the jquery styles affecting the tabbed content.

I suppose I could override their ui-widget styles and put nothing under the definitions? But I would like to know if there is a cleaner way so that their ui-widget styles don't get applied at all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `! important` in your styles. this indicates that nothing else is supposed to override your styles.

Check this [link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm) for details.

Comment: Thanks Vinay. I am trying to avoid this as there is lots of content with lots of different styles and classes within the tab content and do not want to have to go and change each and every style just to accommodate the tabs. 

Thanks for the article on !important though -  I always thought it was a hack that prevented styles being overridded, but I now see it is in fact part of css.

Comment: I don't believe using !important is a good solution to this.  Consider your body font style.  If you set !important on your body font, you lose your capacity to override that font elsewhere.

Personally I think your best bet is to dynamically remove jQuery's class names, and re-style the missing parts.

Answer (score 6):

you could use `removeClass()` to remove class values but the widget might not work if you do.

example:

```
$('.myitem').removeClass('ui-widget');
```

I suggest you add new class values using `addClass()` to overide the styles

**example:**

```
$('.myitem').addClass('newClass');
```

or target the element(s)

```
$('p').addCLass('newClass');
```

and call the function at the end of your widget declaration.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#MyItem").draggable();
    //here
    $("#MyItem").addClass("newClass");

});
```

Comment: Hi - thanks but as already mentioned, there are lots of inputs each with different classes. It's not practical to do it this way. As mentioned, I could do it by overriding the ui-widget styles. That would take a minimal amount of coding and work for all implementations of the jquery tabs throughout the site. 
However, there I am positive that there might be a more efficient or "official" way to stop this happening.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it using .removeClass as dany suggested:

```
$("#menu").tabs();
$("#menu, #menu *").removeClass(function(index, class) {
    // I want to keep these classes because I style them myself,
    // so remove them from the string of classes
    class = class.replace(/ui-tabs-nav|ui-state-active|ui-tabs-hide/,'');
    // Create array of remaining classes that begin with "ui-"
    var matches = class.match(/ui-\S+/g) || [];
    // return classes as space-delimited list
    return (matches.join(' '));
});
```

h/t to [@fancyPT](http://twitter.com/fancyPT) for his generic class removal example on the [.removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) page.

Answer (score 3):

I know its one year later but I found out that this section of the UI.css file was the primary culprit of style propagation:

```
/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-widget { /*font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1.1em; */}
.ui-widget .ui-widget { font-size: 1em; }
.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button {/* font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1em;*/ }
.ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #dddddd; background: #eeeeee url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png) 50% top repeat-x; color: #333333; }
.ui-widget-content a { color: #333333; }
.ui-widget-header { border: 1px solid #e78f08; background: #f6a828 url(images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_f6a828_500x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; }
.ui-widget-header a { color: #ffffff; }
```

Commenting it out will solve most of the problems (well, until you update the UI again).

Comment: What if in case of cdn ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to include any css for tabs.
Just put one css line: 
`.ui-tabs-hide  { display:none; }`
and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can put you tab content in iframe and add diffrent style with style tag in head of iframe content.